# eCryptfs: what if I remove ~/.ecryptfs

Tags: encryption, linux, aes, file-encryption

I'm learning how to use eCryptfs: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs

I get things as below from the link:

> This is used to derive the actual file encryption master key. Thus,
>   you should not enter a custom one unless you know what you are doing -
>   instead press Enter to let it auto-generate a secure random one. It
>   will be encrypted using the login passphrase and stored in this
>   encrypted form in ~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase. Later it will
>   automatically be decrypted ("unwrapped") again in RAM when needed, so
>   you never have to enter it manually. Make sure this file does not get
>   lost, otherwise you can never access your encrypted folder again!

So I did a simple test:

```
ecryptfs-setup-private
mkdir -p ~/test
mount -t ecryptfs ~/test ~/test
cd ~/test && vim data
umount -t ecryptfs ~/test
```

For now, I did get an encrypted file, which means that `~/test/data` was unreadable.
Of course, if I mount it again, I can read it.

Now, I delete ~/.ecryptfs: `rm -rf ~/.ecryptfs`.
Then I try to mount it: `mount -t ecryptfs ~/test ~/test`

To my surprise, I can still mount it and read the `~/test/data`.

Now I'm confused. I thought I could move `~/.encryptfs` into some USB to keep my secret data secure. But it doesn't seem to work because I can still mount it even if I delete `~/.encryptfs`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did your mount command ran without any problems? Did it really mount the fs successfully?

Comment: The documentation is referring to `ecryptfs-setup-private` which uses a wrapped passphrase. Your test does not create a wrapped passphrase, and so the original passphrase is sufficient to decrypt the files.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald  I don't quite understand. I'm sorry but I've executed `exryptfs-setup-private` at the beginning. Maybe I do it in a wrong way?

Comment: @Yves You don't indicate in the question that you used `ecryptfs-setup-private` when doing your test.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald   Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reading of the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ecryptfs-setup-private) and a quick skim of the [source](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ecryptfs/ecryptfs/trunk/view/894/src/utils/ecryptfs-setup-private) to confirm indicates that (among other things) `ecryptfs-setup-private` creates a directory with encrypted data at `~/.Private`, creates a mountpoint for decrypted data at `~/Private`, and encrypts the encryption key with the login passphrase at `~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase`. These paths are not configurable.

What you've done is create an ecryptfs directory at `~/.Private` with a wrapped passphrase, then created a separate ecryptfs directory at `~/test` using your passphrase directly as the key (bad idea). If you want to test that wrapped passphrases work properly you will need to use the `~/Private` directory instead of trying to create your own.